# blackberry webworks access to URL not allowed?

Tags: javascript, cordova, jquery-mobile, blackberry-10, blackberry-webworks

I have completed web-works software setup like "blackberry Web-works
2.2.0.15" and "blackberry 10 device simulator BB10_3_1.995".

when I launch my application on BlackBerry emulator it keeps showing me Access to (some link) not allowed.
I have tried adding to config.xml file

```
<access origin="*"/>
<access origin="https://somedomain.com" subdomains="true" />
```

But the message still keeps showing. The application works on IOS and Android.
Any ideas how to fix it?

I have attached screen shot.

[image]

First ip error message showing. then after url javascript error message.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled over this a while ago. Give this a try:

```
<feature id="blackberry.app">
   <param name="websecurity" value="disable" />
</feature>
```

You can add it to the BB10 config.xml in platforms/blackberry10

Source: http://devblog.blackberry.com/2013/08/accessing-external-resources-in-a-blackberry-10-webworks-app-enterprise-dev-2/

Good luck!

Comment: HI @hanamj i have added above code. but still same error message. any others idea.

Comment: That is for WebWorks 1.0. For WebWorks 2.0 and later, you need: <preference name="WebSecurity" value="disable" />

Answer (score 0):

Add the IP of the server you wish to reach specifically to the access list:

```
<access origin="http://54.88.20.251" subdomains="true" />
```

Or, you can turn off websecurity entirely, which is necessary if you are connecting to a lot of different locations that you don't know in advance. That's done with this in your config file (for WebWorks 2.x):

```
<preference name="WebSecurity" value="disable" />
```